# Ubuntu 14.04.03 blank screen on install (Nvidia 970 Graphics Card)

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, graphics, wubi

When installing Ubuntu 14.04.03 alongside Windows 10 using wubi the installer seems to start, but never displays anything on the screen. This is the hardware I am trying to install it on http://pcpartpicker.com/user/Bridge220/saved/3VgfrH
Wubi shows no errors when running in Windows, and Ubuntu shows up as an option to boot into. The installer seems to start, but does not display anything to the screen (The keyboard lights respond, but not the monitor)

Edit: Update: I now have a display working (yay!), but it does not recognize any of the windows partitions on drives. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu. Since the question has changed in search of the answer please consider updating the question or close it and file a new question. This to avoid multiple issues within one question. See also [about] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Ubuntu by using wubi is not recommended and may lead to a lot of trouble.
Completely remove the wubi installation from the disk - then start over from scratch.
Create an installation media ... boot from it ... highlight Try Ubuntu without installing.

On the live desktop press the Windows key and type GParted into the search field.
Open GParted and reduce the Windows partition if there is no unallocated space.
Create two new partitions - format one with ext4 and the other with linux-swap.

Start the Ubuntu installer and when asked what to do, choose Something else.
Select the ext4 partition that you created and choose root `/` as mount point.
Select the disk on which Windows is installed to install the GRUB boot loader.

Boot into BIOS and choose Ubuntu as the default operating system to boot.
The first action you should perform : install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.
Do not forget to disable hibernation and fast startup in Windows before.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

When the grub appears, press E to edit the commands before booting.

Add the command `nomodeset` after after the commands `quiet` and `nosplash` (No ideal if adding after this matters, but this is how it worked for me.

The screen will go dark, but after some time it should work. After that you can Troubbleshoot further.

**Method 2**

Try changing your primary display adapter in the BIOS to your onboard display. (The one not your GPU) Then plug your monitor in there.

Then you can troubbleshoot.

**Method 3**

Choose `advanced options for ubuntu` in the BIOS and then choose advanced troubbleshooting.

Now choose fallback graphics.

Again, now you should be able to troubbleshoot.

Comment: Xeon E3-1231v3 has no integrated graphics, method 2 will not work

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment, as it doesn't really provide a solution to the problem. It's simply steps that will enable @DanielGrimshaw to further troubleshoot.